# Does Google Cloud SQL support distributed features?

Tags: sql, cloud, distributed

I am reading the document of Google Cloud SQL. But I am not sure if it supports some distributed features or not?

1. mysql master and slave cluster
2. mysql sharding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The beauty of the Google Cloud SQL for its App Engine service is that Google abstracts the High-Availability responsibilities from you. Behind the scene, Google is doing what you are asking for you.